# Database Queries in MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop

In a MVC project if I put **LINQ** queries in `Model`, is it against the MVC Pattern?

```
namespace DocLibrary.Models
{
    public class Author
    {
        private DocLibraryContext db = new DocLibraryContext();

        [Key]
        public Int32 AuthorId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        ..

        public string GetNameById(int AuthorId)
        {
            var query = from a in db.Author
                        where a.AuthorId == AuthorId
                        select a.Name;

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }


        public Author GetAuthorById(int AuthorId)
        {
            var query = from a in db.Author
                        where a.AuthorId.Equals(AuthorId)
                        select a;

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Or should I move these methods (`GetNameById`, `GetAuthorById`) to Controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In a MVC project if I put LINQ queries in Model, is it against the MVC Pattern?

No, it's not against the MVC pattern. Database queries are perfectly fine in the Model. Obviously a clear distinction should be made between the Model and the View Model that you are passing to your views. The view model should not contain any database specific stuff.

> Or should I move these methods (GetNameById, GetAuthorById) to Controller?

Absolutely not. The controller's responsibility is not to query a database. A controller responsibility is to talk to the Model, build a view model and pass this view model to the view. A controller shouldn't even know what a database is.

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
internal IQueryable<Table1> GetArmyList2()
    {
        //var lists = from list in db.Table1
                 //   select list;

        //return lists;


        var query = from Table1 in db.Table1
                    where Table1.Username.Equals("asik") & Table1.Password.Equals("asik")
                    select Table1;

        return query;


    }
```

and controller code

```
public ActionResult asik()
    {
        var armyList = cl.GetArmyList2();
        return View(armyList);
        // return View();
    }
```